# Is it possible to make a stage accessible in all scripts using CreateJS?

Tags: javascript, createjs

I want to add a Bitmap to the stage from a different script than the one it is created in. Is this possible? Currently it gives the error "stage is not defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put "stage" in the global scope you can access it from anywhere.

File #1:

```
var stage;
function init()
{
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
}
```

File #2

```
stage.addChild(bitmap);
```

You can (and should) read more about scope [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)